# Fetching min/max value ranges from a table using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `venue_parameters`:

[image]

Where `min_capacity` and `max_capacity` are defined by drop-down values:

> options = 0-50, options = 50-100 , options = 100-150

When I select the option `50-100` where `minvalue=50` and `maxvalue=100`, I want to get the exact data in `venue_parameters` table.

My query is as follows:

```
$venueQuery->whereHas(
    'venueParameter', 
    function ($query) use ($capacity, $min) {
        $query->where('venue_parameters.max_capacity','<=', $capacity) 
              ->where('venue_parameters.min_capacity','>=', $min);
    }
);
```

Comment: what you tried seems to be correct. any problem with it?

Comment: According to your data set there are no matching rows where min_capacity >= 50 and max_capacity <=100

Comment: MKhalidJunaid You are right. @dashinglove143: You need to reset DB data as your options or you need  to set options as your db data!

Comment: `$query->where('venue_parameters.105','<=', 100)` so this is true right and `->where('venue_parameters.55 ' , '>=' , 50);`  this condition false so it is returns 0

Comment: Improved the formatting for readability and updated the grammar and the title.

Comment: @TomJowitt sure.!!